# Select hidden input from within next td [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, hidden-field

I have a table layed out like this:

```
        <td>
                somename
        </td>
        <td class="hoverable value" >
                somevalue
        </td>
        <td class="changed">

        </td>
        <td class="original value">
            <input type="hidden" value="somevalue" />
        </td>
```

And what I'm trying to do is, I hover over the hoverable td which turns it into a textbox. Once I hover out I want to check the hidden field for it's original value and put an image in changed if the 2 are different from each other. I already have this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var newHTML = '';

    $('table td.hoverable').hover(
    function () {
        var oldHTML = $(this).html().trim();
        $(this).html('<input type=\'text\' value=\'' + oldHTML + '\' size=\'' + ((oldHTML).length + 2) +'\' />');
    },
    function() {
        newHTML = $('input', this).val();
        var oldHTML = $(this).next('td.original').children('hidden').val();
       if(newHTML != oldHTML) {
            $(this).next('td.changed').html('Changed');
        }
        $(this).html(newHTML);
    })
});
```

but it doesn't work. What fails apparently is grabbing the value of the hidden field, and I've tried selecting it in several different ways but just can't get to it.
Any ideas or tips are gratefully appreciated ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **.nextAll()**

```
var oldHTML = $(this).nextAll('td.original').find('input:hidden').val();
```

Why?  Because [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)  is taking the next element and seeing if it matches the selector.  If you use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) you get the next element that matches the selector.

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks a lot! Good to know the difference.

Comment: The jQuery documentation says .next() works exactly this way, but not in a way that it's intuitively understood.  This behavior threw me when I tried to do the exact same thing recently.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).next('td.original').find('input:hidden').val();
```

Comment: Nope, it keeps returning 'undefined'

Comment: This may not have helped solve the original problem, but it helped me with a syntax issue.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldHTML = $(this).next('td.original').children(':hidden').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var oldHTML = $(this).next('td.original').children('hidden').val();
```

With

```
var oldHTML = $(this).next('td.original').find('input:hidden').val();
```